# How to auto-start a program in a standalone session?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-classic, autostart

I have made a new stand alone session like in this [topic](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-create-standalone-compiz-session.html), but i want to auto-start dockbarx in only this session i follow this [topic](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/make-applications-autostart-only-in.html) but it is auto-start in all gnome-fallback sessions, so what to do ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link you show already contain the line

```
dockx &
```

in the last Code frame, relative to `~/.compiz-session`. I suppose editing this file as you like should solve the problem.

Comment: i have done this but didn't work dockbarx didn't start, so what to do ???